# Javscript implementation of Shamir's threshold secret sharing scheme : share()

Tags: javascript, node.js, seal

I have a project of an end-to-end verifiable online voting system. I generated the private key for encryption using the node-seal library available online. I was trying to split the private key into multiple shares using [Shamir's threshold secret sharing scheme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/secrets.js-grempe#installation-and-usage). The secret key i generated is in base64string format. When trying to split the key I had to first covert it into hex which went fine but when I tried to split the key I got the following error:

> Error: Invalid hex character.
>   at hex2bin (/home/shabeeh/node_modules/secrets.js/secrets.js:458:10)
>   at Object.exports.share (/home/shabeeh/node_modules/secrets.js/secrets.js:229:17)
>   at /home/shabeeh/iMatter/iMatter-Web/server/SplitKey.js:75:30 Error: Invalid hex character.
>   at hex2bin (/home/shabeeh/node_modules/secrets.js/secrets.js:458:10)
>    at Object.exports.share (/home/shabeeh/node_modules/secrets.js/secrets.js:229:17)
>   at /home/shabeeh/iMatter/iMatter-Web/server/SplitKey.js:75:30
>    /home/shabeeh/iMatter/iMatter-Web/node_modules/node-seal/dist/seal.node.js:1
>
> !function(A,I){if("object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof
>   module)module.exports=I();else if("function"==typeof
>   define&&define.amd)define([],I);else{var g=I();for(var C in
>   g)("object"==typeof exports?exports:A)[C]=g[C]}}("undefined"!=typeof
>   self?self:this,(function(){return function(A){var I={};function
>   g(C){if(I[C])return I[C].exports;var
>   B=I[C]={i:C,l:!1,exports:{}};return
>   A[C].call(B.exports,B,B.exports,g),B.l=!0,B.exports}return
>   g.m=A,g.c=I,g.d=function(A,I,C){g.o(A,I)||Object.defineProperty(A,I,{enumerable:!0,get:C})},g.r=function(A){"undefined"!=typeof
>   Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(A,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(A,"__esModule",{value:!0})},g.t=function(A,I){if(1&I&&(A=g(A)),8&I)return A;if(4&I&&"object"==typeof A&&A&&A.__esModule)return A;var
>   C=Object.create(null);if(g.r(C),Object.defineProperty(C,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:A}),2&I&&"string"!=typeof
>   A)for(var B in A)g.d(
>
> RuntimeError: abort(Error: Invalid hex character.). Build with -s
>   ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
>       at process.IA (/home/shabeeh/iMatter/iMatter-Web/node_modules/node-seal/dist/seal.node.js:1:5494)
>       at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
>       at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:140:18)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)

I am unable to understand where the problem occurred because the string was converted to hex form, i verified it using `console.log()`.

I am new to `nodejs` and I am extremely sorry if the question is dumb but I am stuck at it and would appreciate any help

Comment: better ask here https://github.com/grempe/secrets.js/issues

Comment: I did. It would be great if someone here could help too.